# Difference between reputation since last view and actual

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page, down-votes

A downvoted and subsequently removed post showed [my reputation activity](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner?tab=reputation) as being -1, which is clearly wrong.

The [now-removed post (answer)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/167889/5764) was the only post affecting my reputation since the last view (as can be seen by the yellow shade), so it should have been 0.

[image]

Comment: I think that event such as "removed" does not affect this specific counter. Not sure if a bug.

Comment: Since it affects reputation, it should affect the reference to *reputation* in my opinion.

Comment: Of course it should, ideally. But I believe that counter just counts the basic reputation events i.e. upvotes, downvotes, bounty, accepts, edits while the +1 is result of external process that does not bother to update the counters. In my opinion it's too minor, but I'm not in a position to decide of course. :)